# Simplifying Algebraic Expression With Substitution

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

Is there a way I can make an algebraic substitution in a matrix? I tried using

```
Simplify[P_rhs _ 51, (c44hat*rhohat)^.5 == zeta]
```

Where P_rhs_51 is a 4x4 matrix.

2 x 2 example:

```
P51 = {{(rhohat*c44hat)^.5, -(rhohat*c44hat)^.5}, {rhohat, rhohat}};
```

Comment: You must not use underscores (`_`) for variable names in _Mathematica_. They have a built-in meaning (see `Blank`). You might also be interested in `ReplaceAll` (and its infix form `/.`).

Comment: Yes, there is such a way. You may get a better answer, if you post your expressions, such that we could copy/paste and play with them.

Comment: P51 = {{(rhohat*c44hat)^.5, -(rhohat*c44hat)^.5}, {rhohat, rhohat}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
P51 = {{(rhohat*c44hat)^.5, -(rhohat*c44hat)^.5}, {rhohat, rhohat}};

P51 /. (c44hat*rhohat)^.5 -> zeta

(*  {{zeta, -zeta}, {rhohat, rhohat}}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you. Legend.